# HTML in Confirmation Screen Introductory Text

Tags: civievent

We have text that goes on the top of our Registration Screen Confirmation Screen, and our Thank You Screen. It's the exact same text - name and date of the event in big letters. It's working fine on the Registration Screen and the Thank You Screen; however, on the Confirmation Screen it's showing the HTML instead of processing it.

Everything was fine previously, but we just updated to the latest version of CiviCRM for D7 and now this is happening.

I removed all our custom template files, deleted the cache, etc just in case it was an issue with our custom templates. The problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `escape` in this line to `purify`, does that fix it: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/e33e2dee8fb57eac6a068629ec5224ab9d3576c4#diff-6f590560a3250af349b62a231b13cbfb124c191e07f69319d1b5aade2d688349R38

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/29841

Comment: That did it, thanks! Now, I just need to get it all over to my custom version.